# Do recommended deletions turn into delete votes when the delete privilege is earned?

Tags: support, privileges, deleted-answers

Users with >2k rep but <20k (1k and 4k respectively on beta sites) can recommend deletion on low quality answers. Once the upper bound is reached, users unlock the ability to cast delete votes on an answer. It takes 6 recommended deletions or 3 delete votes to delete a low quality question.

If someone were to recommend deletion on an answer and then gain the rep needed to unlock the delete vote privilege before their recommended deletion expired or the post was deleted, would their recommended deletion convert into a delete vote? For example: If a post had 2 "recommended deletions" and 2 delete votes, would it be deleted if one of the users who had recommended deletion earned the privilege to cast delete votes?

Comment: Just to note: for the purposes of review, a "Delete" review counts the same as a "Recommend Deletion" review. The only difference is that the former also at the same time casts a delete vote. Once a user earns trusted user privileges, they can later vote to delete a post they gave the latter review, effectively equating the actions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: no, it would still be recorded as a Recommend Deletion review.

Here's the reasoning for this: if a user reviewed something when they had 19k reputation, the system determines that that user is not yet experienced enough to use the 20k tools. This is why users with <20k have the Recommend Deletion button rather than Delete.

If the user then proceeds to gain 20k, the system determines that they are now experienced enough to vote to delete answers. However, if a user had recommend deletioned something before that, they were not considered experienced enough at the time.

It doesn't matter how much reputation they have *now*; it matters how much experience they had *when they performed the review*. Their opinion may have changed since then, and changing the review could be harmful.

Comment: To clarify: it is possible for users who've later earned 20k+ rep to later vote to delete even if they've reviewed "Recommend Deletion" in the past.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog yes. Reviews do not affect votes you can cast on a post.

Comment: Similarly if you lose the rep you should be kicked out of the queue (and presumably wouldn't re-enter if you gain it back). I can't find anything that says that would happen, only that badges earned are kept even if you no longer have what initially qualified you to receive said badge while reputation lost equals privilege lost (and regained when reputation rises past the demarcation).

Comment: Unrelated, but why does everyone on MSE have "Wizard" in their name now?

Comment: @TheWanderer see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/325465#325465

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks for asking. I was concerned that his wiz was purple, but I didn't want to bring it up.